# Why there is not model() method in model class in Yii2

Tags: yii2

I have created a some models using Gii in Yii2. But there are no model() methods in these classes. Why is it so?

As I remember this method was in Yii1 created models. Am I wrong?

Comment: Why do you expect that methods used in previous framework version are available in new one? See the [Yii 2 Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html) for details about working with ActiveRecord models.

Comment: I thought so because I see some codes of other people written in Yii2 and have model() method, so I thought it should be there.